# How can I implement AND and OR operations in C++

Tags: c++, mips, instructions

I have an assignment that I'm supposed to implement the MIPS processor in C++ and one of the MIPS instructions is "AND" and "OR" the MIPS instruction is represented as `and $s1,$s2,$s3` which means that `$s1=$s2(and)$s3` the `$s2 and $s3` registers are represented into bits ,,, how can I perform the "AND" and "OR" operations using C++?

Comment: +1 for the interesting topic ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are both binary and logical and and or operators in C++.

```
int a, b = 1;

int x = a | b; // binary OR
int x = a & b; // binary AND
bool x = a || b; // boolean OR
bool x = a && b; // boolean AND
```

Comment: By *binary*, he meant *bitwise* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation). Bitwise boolean AND/OR/NOT operators work bit-by-bit on word operands. Logical operators work on `bool` operands.

Comment: There is no "Like" button so I just upped you. +1

Comment: Sometimes it output some weird numbers for example 110010 & 010101 = 110591 Why does that happen

Comment: @Shadi: C++ does not support binary literals. You are &ing the decimal numbers `110010` and `010101`, not binary numbers.

Answer (score 0):

A boolean comparison will return true or false depending on the value of the two operands. Logical "and" will return true if both operands are non-zero. Logical "or" will return false only if both operands are false.

Bitwise operators are different and operate on the bits of the operands. A bit wise "and" will set a bit to true only if both corresponding bits are true:

```
101 & 110 = 100
```

Bitwise "or" sets a bit to zero only if both corresponding bits are zero:

```
010 | 001 = 011
```

The two bitwise comparison operators are more closely related to the shift operators (<< and >>) and the one's complement operator (~) in that they are low level operations.

Comment: Sometimes it otput som weird numbers for example
110010 &
010101
=
110591
Why does that happen

Comment: I posted the numbers in binary (base 2). You're looking at numbers in base 10. 5 base 10 == 101 base 2.