# Error implementing "AND" and "OR" in c++

Tags: c++, mips, instructions

With reference to my previous question, [How can i implement AND and OR operations in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246819/how-can-i-implement-and-and-or-operations-in-c)

My next question is, Sometimes it outputs some weird numbers for example 110010 & 010101 = 110591. Why does that happen?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    long int s;
    long int l;
    long int r;

    cin>>s;
    cout<<endl;
    cin>>l;
    cout<<setfill('0')<<setw (5)<<s<<endl<<setfill('0')<<setw (5)<<l<<endl;
    r=s|l;
    cout<<r<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: They aren't "weird numbers" if you know what they do ;)

Comment: Please post the code you are using, because those numbers don't make sense. With positive numbers *x* and *y*, *z* = *x* & *y*, *z* cannot be greater than *x* and *z* cannot be greater than *y*.

Comment: // setw example
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  long int s;
  long int l;
  long int r;
  cin>>s;
  cout<<endl;
  cin>>l;
  cout<<setfill('0')<<setw (5)<<s<<endl<<setfill('0')<<setw (5)<<l<<endl;
  r=s|l;
  cout<<r<<endl;
  return 0;
}

Comment: @Shadi: In your code, you are using `|`. Your question asks about `&`. That is the difference.

Comment: Yes, I am supposed to use both the error appears in both cases

Comment: something in your code is wrong, but since you didn't post any code, nobody can give you an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the question -- how to input binary numbers instead of decimal.

You can read them as strings, and then convert them assuming that they are base 2.

So, code like this (not tested!):

```
std::string s_str;

cin >> s_str;
...
// now convert as if it's a binary string, thats what the last arg following does
s = strtol(s_str.c_str(), 0, 2);
```

Comment: I SWEAR TO GOD BEST ANSWER EVER,, and only 11 rep. god bless "u" man

Answer (score 6):

You appear to be typing in the number `110010` and expecting that to be in binary because it only has 1s and 0s. That number is a *decimal* number, and you need to convert it to binary so that the bitwise operations will make sense.

```
 decimal                    binary
 ---------------------------------
 110010 = 0001 1010 1101 1011 1010
 010101 = 0000 0010 0111 0111 0101
 ---------------------------------
 110591 = 0001 1010 1111 1111 1111 (result of a | b)
```

The above is the binary representation of the numbers you are using, divided into groups of four bits so it's easier to read.

Comment: Yes so ur saying that the numbers i inputed are decimal numbers not binary,, thats why i get an error, how can i represent them in binary so i can get the right answer

Comment: You could convert your desired values into decimal before typing them in. `110010 = 50` and `010101 = 21`. `50 | 21 = 55`, or `110111` in binary. Get yourself a good calculator with hex/decimal/binary conversions and this will become a lot easier.

Comment: ahhh ,, now things are much clearer how can i do this operation in c++ without any calculators, ??

Comment: @Shadi: Instead of using decimals, you should use hex notation. It's easier to mentally convert between binary and hex than binary and decimal. Take your binary number and split it into groups of four bits. If the number of bits isn't a multiple of 4, add leading zeros to make it so. Convert each group of four bits into its decimal representation, which will always be a number between 0 and 15. The decimals are then converted to their corresponding hex digit. Decimal values from 0 to 9 are the same in hex, while 10 == A, 11 == B, 12 == C, 13 == D, 14 == E and 15 == F.

Comment: C++ does not contain any inbuilt means for specifying binary constant values.

Comment: @Shadi: First a comment: Don't use textspeak. Use you are, you're, or your, but never ur. Textspeak makes you look lazy and stupid. Now for your (not ur) question: You can't enter or print data in binary in C++. What you can do is enter or print data in octal or hexadecimal, either one of which is easy to convert to/from binary.

Comment: @Shadi: For example, the binary number `110010` has 6 digits. We add two leading zero bits to make it 8 digits (a multiple of 4): `00110010`. Split it into groups of four: `0011 0010`. Convert each group into a decimal representation: `3 2`. Then convert these numbers to their hex digit, which in this case is `32`. So the binary number `110010` can be represented by `0x32`. You can then use `0x32` in your source code to represent the binary number `110010`.

Comment: @David Hammen OMG man , "you are" a programmer your supposed to type fast i dont stop and think about these things just, thats the way i write and i am pretty sure thats how you write too

Comment: @Shadi: Actually no we don't. On this site we expect some bit of professionalism. And if you can type fast, then `ur` and `you are` are of no consequence.

Comment: @Shadi: No, that is not the way I write. I do make typing errors, but  I do not revel in them. I am embarrassed by them.

Answer (score 3):

For your last questions:

> My other questions is,,Sometimes it
>   output some weird numbers for example
>   110010 & 010101 = 110591 Why does that
>   happen

This notation that you've written is queer. The 1st number is treated as a decimal. The 2nd number which is '010101' is treated as an octal number as it beings with a '0'. The output should be 0 for the numbers that you've chosen when displayed as an integer.

That being said, are you sure you got your notations right? Also, be very specific with the numbers when you want to do a bit-wise &.

Lastly, if you really need to deal with binary, some compilers allow for the '0b' notation. For others, we're really comfortable with using HEX i.e.: '0x'

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: I only want to use bitwise operations "&" and "|" i dont want ocatal or anything else how can i fix it??

Comment: @Shadi: Why not? It doesn't matter what number representation you use, the bitwise operations operate only on the bits. For example, `255`, `0377`, and `0xff` all represent the same number. `120 & 43` gives you the exact same value as `0x78 & 0x2b`. Hex notation is used because the correspondence between hex and binary is much more obvious.

Comment: @Shadi: Yes, I agree with In silico. He's right, most programmers are really comfortable with the HEX notation '0x'. That said, if you don'twant octals, then be sure not to append '0' in front of the numbers that you're using. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Use the std::bitset to get binary values from a stream:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main() 
{
    std::bitset<8>  val1;
    std::bitset<8>  val2;

    std::cin >> val1 >> val2;

    std::cout << val1 << " = " << val1.to_ulong() << "\n";
    std::cout << val2 << " = " << val2.to_ulong() << "\n";
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    std::cout << (val1 | val2) << " = " << (val1.to_ulong() | val2.to_ulong()) << "\n";

}
```

Running:

```
> g++ t.cpp
> ./a.out
110010
010101
00110010 = 50
00010101 = 21


00110111 = 55
```

Answer (score 1):

`a = b && c;` will preform logical ***and*** operation and store it into a;
`a = b || c;` will preform logical ***or*** operation and store it into a;

`a = b & c;` will preform bitwise ***and*** operation and store it into a;
`a = b | c;` will preform bitwise ***or*** operation and store it into a;

examples :

```
11 && 10 = 01
10 && 01 = 01
00 && 11 = 00

11 || 10 = 01
10 || 01 = 01
00 || 11 = 01

11  & 10 = 10
10  & 01 = 00
00  & 11 = 00

11  | 10 = 11
10  | 01 = 11
00  | 11 = 11
```

Comment: so instead of using a=b&c i use a=b&&c and the same for "or"

Comment: if you only want to check between true and false yes

Comment: no no no i want the a=b&c to give me NOT true or false but the actual bitwise operations but it works sometimes but sometimes gives me an error as shown in the question

Comment: @shadi then I can't understand your example: if your example is written in binary system how can there be 5 or 9 in it and if it's not the result of that operation is 9520, there is something wrong in another place in your code.

Comment: && and || are not binary operations, they are logical operators

Comment: plz check the code i posted on my question, i really dont know what the problem is but i hope u guys can fix it

Comment: first dont' paste code as comment! second in your code you are using logical operator ***or*** not and, that's why the result is larger than both b and c. and you are asking user some decimal values and printing result in decimal so it's doing operation correctly. the real operation you are doing is `11010110110111010 or 10011101110101 = 11010111111111111`

Comment: Yes i know the error happens using both, just consider i used both

Comment: @GeneBushuyev don't be hard on words, I mean logical and binary has the same meaning compared to bitwise operation! but edited to correct it. thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Yes I understood the problem thanks for that , the problem as i understand it is that The numbers iam entering are decimal numbers and when ther are "ored" its correct but still represented in decimal value how can i fix it

Comment: as far as I know you have to implement yourself how to print or read something in a binary value but it's rather easy job only needs a while loop to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want binary operations your inputs must be in binary, not decimal or octal.

Unfortunately C and C++ don't appear to support binary literals. Some compilers let you do them with an '0b' prefix, so `110010 & 010101` would be written `0b110010 & 0b010101`, but apparently that's not portable.

One option is to use a [std::bitset](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/bitset.html), which lets you enter a binary number as a string.

However, given that you've noted that this is homework, I expect an std::bitset is not the answer that you are expected to provide, and can just use & and | normally. The only reason you see a problem is because you enter binary numbers in decimal and octal format - if you enter and manipulate numbers all in one format then there will be no problem.

Comment: i can use std::bitset, but if i cant how can i manipulate the numbers so that i can get the write answers

Comment: If your task is, as the other question suggests, to "implement the MIPS processor", then at no point do you need to store a number in binary form in a string.